# Custom ggplot theme produces diffrent result even if I use the same code for booth plots. Bug or user error?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to create a custom theme to save some time with ggplot, but ran in to some trouble. Why is it that PLOT 1 and PLOT 2 give different result? Notice how the x-axis text change. I was expecting these two plots to be exactly the same!

```
# basic plot
p <- ggplot(cars, aes(
  
  x = speed,
  y = dist)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6) + 
  
  labs(
    x ="Distance", 
    y = "Speed", 
    title = "Car speed analysis") 

# PLOT 1: add theme_bw with some customization

p +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(
  # Title
  plot.title = element_text(
    size = 18, # font size
    hjust = 0, # alignment (o = left, 1 = right, 0.5 = center)
    vjust = 1.4), # up/down
  
  # x- and y-axis labels
  axis.title.x = 
    element_text(size = 15),
  axis.title.y = 
    element_text(size = 15),
  legend.position = "bottom"
)

# save customization as theme_cust
theme_cust <- function(){ 
  theme_bw() %+replace%
    
    theme(
      # Title
      plot.title = element_text(
        size = 18, # font size
        hjust = 0, # alignment (o = left, 1 = right, 0.5 = center)
        vjust = 1.4), # up/down
      
      # x- and y-axis labels
      axis.title.x = 
        element_text(size = 15),
      axis.title.y = 
        element_text(size = 15),
      legend.position = "bottom"
    )}

# PLOT 2: se custom theme on basic plot

p + theme_cust()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it just as I posted this. I'm not sure this is the right / best way to do this, but all I did was to change `%+replace%` to `+`. That's it. Its a bit confusing as it seems that `%+replace%` seems to work for other people.